# DB Transaction Grouping - Spring,java - Looking for design ideas

Tags: java, spring

An application is being built using Spring REST Controllers, Spring JDBC, and RDBMS. 
The Service would perform multiple DB operations within single transaction boundary. We need to identify the rows that are inserted as part of same transaction for future reporting.

Proposed solution

- Create a Transaction_Grp column in all DB tables
- Add a field transactionGroup on all Entity objects
- In the Service method, generate a unique id and set it as
  transactionGroup on all Entity objects used within the method
  transaction boundary.
- Insert the same transactionGroup value into all the DB tables that
  are part of same transaction.

Are there any better solutions/ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. Batch_ID or Transaction_Group_ID could be introduced in all tables (entities) that need to be tracked and taken care of by all DML operations.

Many think this would lead to polluting the main tables with unnecessary information. Hence resort to turning this approach over its head completely. One may introduce a table that maps primary keys of all tables (entities) and entity names against an id in this table. In other words, one may introduce a table called transaction_groups with transaction_group_id, participant_entity_id and participant_entity_name and map all information in this table.

Choice is yours!!

Comment: Thank you, we are also considering similar approach of having another table to store transaction group id, all entity ids etc.

Comment: I encourage you to upvote or elect correct answer in case it meets your requirement or is helpful. Helps other to find it when they are looking for answers on similar questions.